# Marriage between close relatives

Tags: synonyms

What is the English term for *marriage between close relatives?*

Comment: The closest marriages which are legally permitted under English law are those between first cousins. As far as I know there is no special name for them. But are you talking about illegal marriages between closer relatives than this? Again there is no name so far as I know other than 'unlawful marriage'.

Comment: We have _incest_ for sex between close relatives, but no single word for marriage between them. Marriage between siblings is just called _sibling marriage_.

Answer (score 10):

The most commonly used word would be *incest*, although technically, incest refers to sex between (close) relatives. However, since a marriage is usually supposed to be consummated (meaning the partners in the marriage *do* have sex), the word is also applied to marriage.

Although *incestuous marriage* is commonly used, I believe the more correct expression is *[**consanguineous**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consanguineous) marriage*. That simply refers to a marriage between people that are "of the same blood", i.e. they descend from a common close ancestor.

Comment: There are, in fact, *two* sets of taboos: affinity and consanguinity. Consanguinity is about blood relationships; affinity covers the "that's just weird" set (like marrying a stepmother or stepdaughter, where there is no blood relationship but there *is* an equivalent social relationship).  (Charming related movie: 1959's *The Bridal Path*.)

Comment: @bye: the taboo on affinity is, however, usually not as strong as the one on consanguinity. It is indeed the distinction between "that's just weird" and "that's just wrong".

Answer (score 0):

The word you want is "inbreeding".

Comment: _Inbreeding_ does not necessarily involve matrimony... it's also applied to animals, which are known for having sexual relationships out of wedlock. Applied to humans, the expression is pejorative, and the OP does not indicate they are looking for a word with such negative connotations.

Comment: Please give a rationale for your answer.